# nginx + gunicorn 400 error

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have setup my server to use `nginx` plus `gunicorn` for hosting a project. When I send POST request of small sizes everything is OK. But when I send POST requests of size about 5MB I get 400 error from server.

I had set client_max_body_size in my nginx configuration to 100M. Can anyone help with this error? Following is how I send request to server :

```
r = requests.post(url, json=data, timeout=180, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

400 Error depends on `data` size. With large `data` size I get this error!

Comment: Did you checkout this link - http://www.moreiscode.com/uploads-work-with-python-development-server-but-not-nginxgunicorn/

Comment: To sump up @VineethGuna's given link, maybe you need to check the permission of your upload directory. Although I think they are different problems as nginx will return 500 if `gunicorn` doesn't have right permission.

Comment: Special Thanks @VineethGuna for your link. As suggested I ran gunicorn from command line and not daemon. I found the problem is from django settings DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the link suggested in comments I ran `Gunicorn` from command line and send big data request. I saw `Gunicorn` was experiencing :

`Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` error.

As documentations says default value is set to about 2.5MB. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size. After setting it to None Problem solved.

Strange thing is that I didn't get any error in my django project logs!